# Timestamp of file on mounted drive shows 1 hour lag

Tags: files, rhel, virtualbox, timestamps

I have a very specific and a very puzzling problem.

If I modify (touch) file located on mounted drive the file's timestamp shows the latest modification time as exactly one hour before the actual event.

I have checked all possible options I could imagine, but got nowhere.

Here are more details about setup (it is quite complicated).

1. The machine runs RH 6.8  (let us call it rh68).
2. On top of it I run RH 4.8 on virtual box (let us call it rh48vb)
3. Physically, home folder is located on machine with RH 5.5 (rh55) and is mounted on both rh68 & rh48vb

**All machines' clock set to (almost) the same time as shown by 'date' command** with rh48vb clock going about 2 minutes forward

Now, assume I am log on to rh48vb. I have access to home folder (physically located on rh55) and to the /build/ folder, physically located on the local hard drive. I have 2 files named test_home and test_build.

Here is the magic:

```
<rh48vb>cd /build
/build
<rh48vb>date
Mon Jun  5 13:26:52 UTC 2017
<rh48vb>touch test_build
<rh48vb>ll test_build
-rw-r--r-- users 5 Jun  5 13:26 test_build
<rh48vb>cd ~
<rh48vb>date
Mon Jun  5 13:27:04 UTC 2017
<rh48vb>touch test_home
<rh48vb>ll test_home
-rw-r--r--  1 users 5 Jun  5 12:25 test_home

< ....... login to my physical workstation rh68 ........>
<rh68>date
Mon Jun  5 13:25:36 BST 2017
<rh68>ll test_home 
-rw-r--r-- 1 users 5 Jun  5 13:25 test_home

< ....... login to machine rh55 where homefolder physically is located ........>
<rh55> date
Mon Jun  5 13:25:54 BST 2017
<rh55>ll test_home 
-rw-r--r-- 1 users 5 Jun  5 13:25 test_home
```

So

- When I look at file `test_home` from **rh68** or **rh55** timestamp is correct.
- When I look at `test_home` from **rh48vb** the timestamp is **rh55** time of file's modification minus one hour.
- When I look at file `test_build` from **rh48vb** timestamp is **rh48vb** time of file modification.

It does not matter if I 'touch' `time_home` from **rh48** or from **rh68** or **rh55** -- the result is the same.

At this point I have run out of ideas.

Comment: The rh48vb is running on `UTC` and the rh68 on `BST` timezone. You should set them both to the same `BST` timezone and maybe install the ntp service to sync the machine time with the internet. (UTC offset to BST is +1 hour)

Comment: Yes,  `hwclock -r` shows the same time on **rh48vb** and **rh55**. I do not have access rights to run `hwclock -r` on **rh68**.

Comment: @michael-d Aha! Thanks a million! If you make your comment an answer I shall upvote and mark it correspondingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two computers in two different timezones

- **rh48vb** is in UTC time (Universal Time Coordinated aka GTM)
- **rh55** in British Summer Time (BST - GMT +1)

While the time on both computers are equal, the computers don't know that they are in the same timezone or even in the same country - so when ever you do something from to another computer the timezone will always be +/- 1 hour depending from which timezone you interact.

If there is one computer in which you can change the timezone, set it to the same computer's timezone where you can't.

Comment: Sorry, cannot upvote -- not high enough reputation. Marked it as a correct answer, though. Many thanks again.

Comment: Or if it's just about viewing the files, just set the timezone for the user accounts (`export TZ=Europe/London`, or whatever). This is how I deal with machines physically located in different timezones - the hardware clock runs UTC, the default system time is the local timezone, and I have my account set to use my own preferred timezone. (Just need to mind those `crontab` entries...)

Comment: The times on the two computers are *not* equal, actually, and that's the problem. When it's 13:27 UTC on rh48vb, it's 12:25 UTC on rh68. The problem is not the timezone setting, it's the clock setting. This may have been because the time was initially set by entering it in the wrong timezone, but it can't be solved by displaying the time in a different timezone.